# footer line and height of my view keeps changing while resizing the window

Tags: html, css

I have this login page with a footer. the footer keeps chaning its height to the extent that it overlaps with the body. If someone plesae can help. I do not what is going on here. I would like to have the height fixed with no overlaps while taking into account the resizing

[image]

[image]

this is my css

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 30px; 
    margin-top: auto
}
```

I removed `position` it seems better, but the footer has become outside the body/html background

[image]

this is the css of html and body

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume, but i can see what's wrong. Try this:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%; /* fixed it, because the regular height 100% will cause that white background of footer*/
}
body {
    /* we need background image only in body */
    background: url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.footer {
    /* we should remove position or set it relative */
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 30px; 
    margin-top: auto
}
```

Should work perfectly.

Comment: thank you. It worked. but why height was causing the white box?

Comment: 100% height of html and body is a heigh of a viewport, and not a while document. Footer made the common height mor then viewport, but background image was seen only on 100% height of a viewport. Min-heigh released the fixed height.